# FireStore query with OR operator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I had build a social app on firebase 6 months back, initially I was showing all user posts ordered by date in feed. As app has grown up now I want to prioritize friends' post in feed (a very common use case), but this seems impossible in firestore.

Just to show top 10 results in user feed I need to fetch all friends posts (100 friends x 50 posts), rank the post and return top 10 ranked results. Imagine how slow it would be, making 100 connections from client app to server.

Another possilbity could be, prepare the individual user feed beforehand (fanout write) but this need too many writes and requires big storage.
I am thinking to dump firestore and migrate to mongodb.

Is there any solution possible in firestore?

[image: Firebase Structure]

Comment: This question is unclear. We don't have knowledge of how your database is structured or what mechanic would make a friends post 'rank' higher than a non-friends post. You can easily add two observers to FireStore - one general observer for the latest 10 posts and then another for the latest 10 posts by someone in the users friends list. Add those the array first, followed by the 10 general posts and you have a list of 20 posts with friends posts at the top. Please review the following guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay that's my point.. I need add observer for each friend's posts. I can't make an combined observer which listens for posts of these n friends.
Creating a separate observer for each friend is very costly.

Comment: Having multiple observers is not costly. There are many apps that have dozens of observers without any performance degradation - that's how Firestore is designed to work. However, if  the data is structured incorrectly, it can lead to overly complex queries. Without knowing your current structure, platform etc it's going to be hard to help you. Check out [Simple & Compound Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

Comment: @Jay I have uploaded the screenshot of post and friend data structure. I need to first pull all the friends of the current user and then fetch all the posts made by these friends. Later sort these post by latest date and show the sorted post list in current user feed.

Comment: That's Firebase Database, not Firestore. Your question asks about Firestore. There are different solutions (could be the same concept though) for each. However, given we want to watch for new posts with friends inserted at the top of the list (an array) it would be super simple to just add a .child added observer to the posts feed and if the post is from one of the users friends, insert it at the top of an array and if it not add it at a position after the friends posts in the array.